# is ethereum blockchain and data storage scalable (for storage, sync across all nodes) over years and years

Tags: scalability

with every passing year the length of the blockchain and the data stored within, is going to exponentially increase.
every time a new full node joins the network, the entire blockchain and DB(state/storage trie) is replicated
right now, it takes a few hours, but ...
In a few years, how the replication for new full node, is going to remain sustainable ?
many of you might have thought about this, seeking expert opinions and information

Comment: have you searched online for articles about Blockchain scalability or Ethereum 2.0?

Comment: after your suggestion searched web and found this:
But it below only proposed? not yet tried in practice

https://vitalik.ca/general/2021/05/23/scaling.html
"Ethereum is planning to use quadratic sharding, where total scalability is limited by the fact that a node has to be able to process both a single shard and the beacon chain which has to perform some fixed amount of management work for each shard."